# How to parse following JSON using GSON in android?

Tags: android, json, gson

As `keysArray` (A,B,C) are `dynamic` and `cores` having the same object names ? Please help !!!

```
{

 "result":"success",

 "keysArray":[
     "A",
     "B",
     "C",
     "D",
     "E"
     ],

 "cores":{

    "A":[{"key":"value"}],
    "B":[{"key":"value"}],
    "C":[{"key":"value"}],
    "D":[{"key":"value"}],
    "E":[{"key":"value"}]
 }
}
```

Comment: keysArray next time may contain "keysArray":["F","G","H","I","J","K"] and similararly "cores":{FGHIJK}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved it in this way.

```
String responseStr = //JsonResponse here
Type type = new TypeToken<GetMainResponse>() {}.getType();
GetMainResponse getMainResponse = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.TRANSIENT).create().fromJson(responseStr, type);

    int size = getMainResponse.getKeysArray().size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        JSONArray jCoreIngredients = new JSONObject(responseStr)
                                            .getJSONArray(getMainResponse.getKeysArray().get(i));
        String innerStr = jCoreIngredients.toString();
        Type type2 = new TypeToken<ArrayList<GetMainResponse.InnerCores>>() {}.getType();
        ArrayList<GetMainResponse.InnerCores> ingredientsInner = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.TRANSIENT).create().fromJson(innerStr, type2);
    }

//And this is my POJO

public class GetMainResponse{
String result;
ArrayList<String> keysArray;
Cores cores;

public String getResult() { return result; }

public void setResult(String result) { this.result = result; }

public ArrayList<String> getKeysArray() { return keysArray; }

public void setKeysArray(ArrayList<String> keysArray) { this.keysArray = keysArray; }

public Data getCores() { return data; }

public void setCores(Cores cores) { this.cores = cores; }

public class Cores {

// No declaration and not getter setter here.

 public class InnerCores {
    String key;

    public String getKey() { return key; }

    public void setKey(String result) { this.key = key; }

 }
}
```

Any suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

For this i will suggest to use [Go To JsonSchema2Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

To go there and select

- Source Type : JSON
- Annotation style: GSON

And click Preview at bottom side You will get the GSON based Model class

Comment: Dude class names are different for each response. So how can I create Dynamic classes as POJO ?

Comment: Class name or object name ? not getting can you please elaborate

Comment: The imporant things in GSON is the format of json objects and json objects type. I am eager to help you can you please elaborate.I am not getting

Comment: Not an issue with my solution.
Let me explain what i think on your json response
1. KeyArray is Array of [A,B,C,...]
2. Cores is collection of Arrays of A, Arrays of B......
@Abhijeet

Comment: Yes but I can't create a POJO of n number of classes right ?

Comment: You can create the POJO but that create big size interms of more number of classes.If you avoid this multiple POJO you can go with Simple Json library with the help of iterator. For GSON there has to be some preassumtion for response

Answer (score 1):

Try this out its a sample for getting about us status and description.Based on this code you can make yours.
this is the code for your main page.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
AboutUsRootObject joc = gson.fromJson(responseOutput.toString(), AboutUsRootObject.class);
resultStatus = joc.status;
resultOutputMsg = joc.message;
```

then create a new class as **AboutUsRootObject.java** and write this code:

```
 public class AboutUsRootObject {


        public int getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(int status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public AboutUsData getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(AboutUsData data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public int status ;
        public String message ;
        public AboutUsData data ;
    }
```

here you have defined **getter setter** for the data.Here **data** key has some more data in it multiple, as is its **cores** key in yours so again create a new class of getter setter similar as above and proceed.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
try {
            JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(str);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Demo2 demo2 = gson.fromJson(obj1.toString(),Demo2.class);
            data3 = gson.toJson(demo2);
            Log.e("Main Activity",data3.toString());



        }catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and Demo2 class :

```
public class Demo2 {
    private String result;
    private ArrayList<String> keysArray;
    private Core cores;
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getKeysArray() {
        return keysArray;
    }

    public void setKeysArray(ArrayList<String> keysArray) {
        this.keysArray = keysArray;
    }



    private class Core {
        private ArrayList<ClassD> D;
        private ArrayList<ClassE> E;
        private ArrayList<ClassC> C;
        private ArrayList<ClassB> B;
        private ArrayList<ClassA> A;

        public ArrayList<ClassA> getA() {
            return A;
        }

        public ArrayList<ClassB> getB() {
            return B;
        }

        public ArrayList<ClassC> getC() {
            return C;
        }

        public ArrayList<ClassD> getD() {
            return D;
        }

        public ArrayList<ClassE> getE() {
            return E;
        }

        private class ClassA {
            private String key;

            public String getKey() {
                return key;
            }

            public void setKey(String key) {
                this.key = key;
            }
        }

        private class ClassB {
            private String key;

            public String getKey() {
                return key;
            }

            public void setKey(String key) {
                this.key = key;
            }
        }

        private class ClassC {
            private String key;

            public String getKey() {
                return key;
            }

            public void setKey(String key) {
                this.key = key;
            }
        }

        private class ClassE {
            private String key;

            public String getKey() {
                return key;
            }

            public void setKey(String key) {
                this.key = key;
            }
        }

        private class ClassD {
            private String key;

            public String getKey() {
                return key;
            }

            public void setKey(String key) {
                this.key = key;
            }
        }


    }

    public Core getCores() {
        return cores;
    }

    public void setCores(Core cores) {
        this.cores = cores;
    }







}
```