# Parse Dynamic json object in Android

Tags: java, android, json, getjson, baseadapter

I am trying to parse the following `json` and display it in `ListView` using `BaseAdapter`, Android. Here the objects **4** and **1** are **dynamic**.I know how to create a model class if those values are not dynamic. I tried to get the `json` using following way and it doesn't return any value. **Is there anything wrong in `Model.java`? or Should I change format of json?**

```
         {  
   "effect_list":[  
      {  
         "4":[  
            {  
               "effects_id":"18",
               "effects_name":"Band 1"
            },
            {  
               "effects_id":"19",
               "effects_name":"Band 2"
            }
         ],
         "1":[  
            {  
               "effects_id":"1",
               "effects_name":"Background Blur"
            },
            {  
               "effects_id":"4",
               "effects_name":"Blemish Removal"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**Model.java**

```
public class Model{


@SerializedName("effect_list")
@Expose
List<Map<String,List<EffectList>>>  effectlist;

public List<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> getEffectlist() {
    return effectlist;
}

public void setEffectlist(List<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> effectlist) {
    this.effectlist = effectlist;
}
}
```

**EffectList.java**

```
public class EffectList {



@SerializedName("effects_id")
@Expose
private String effectsId;

@SerializedName("effects_name")
@Expose
private String effectsName;



 //GETTERS AND SETTERS


}
```

**MyContactAdapter2.java**

```
public class MyContactAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {


    ArrayList<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> contactList;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public MyContactAdapter2(Context context, ArrayList<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> data) {      
    this.context = context;
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    contactList = data;


}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public List<HashMap<String, List<EffectList>>> getItem(int position) {
    return (List<HashMap<String, List<EffectList>>>) contactList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder1 vh1;
    if (convertView == null) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.get_layout_row_view, parent, false);
        vh1 = ViewHolder1.create((RelativeLayout) view);
        view.setTag(vh1);
    } else {
        vh1 = (ViewHolder1) convertView.getTag();
    }


    EffectList item = (EffectList) getItem(position);


    //   vh.textViewName.setText(item.getEffectsId());


    vh1.textViewName.setText(item.getEffectsName());
    vh1.textViewEmail.setText(item.getEffectsId());

    // Picasso.with(context).load(item.getProfilePic()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(vh.imageView);

    return vh1.rootView;
}


private static class ViewHolder1 {
    public final RelativeLayout rootView;
    public final ImageView imageView;
    public final TextView textViewName;
    public final TextView textViewEmail;

    private ViewHolder1(RelativeLayout rootView, ImageView imageView, TextView textViewName, TextView textViewEmail) {
        this.rootView = rootView;
        this.imageView = imageView;
        this.textViewName = textViewName;
        this.textViewEmail = textViewEmail;
    }

    public static MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder1 create(RelativeLayout rootView) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        TextView textViewEmail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
        return new MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder1(rootView, imageView, textViewName, textViewEmail);
    }
}


}
```

Is there anything wrong in **MyContactAdapter2?**

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355969/how-to-parse-following-json-using-gson-in-android

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change this method

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}
```

Hope This Help

Answer (score 1):

[Have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355969/how-to-parse-following-json-using-gson-in-android)

I am also having same problem regarding parsing with GSON, but achievd by making StringRequest<> instead of GSONRequest<>
Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `POJO Model class` from `JSON` from this website

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

I made this from your `json`! though your `json` should be simpler !

-----------------------------------com.example.EffectList.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class EffectList {

@SerializedName("4")
@Expose
private List<com.example._4> _4 = null;
@SerializedName("1")
@Expose
private List<com.example._1> _1 = null;

public List<com.example._4> get4() {
return _4;
}

public void set4(List<com.example._4> _4) {
this._4 = _4;
}

public List<com.example._1> get1() {
return _1;
}

public void set1(List<com.example._1> _1) {
this._1 = _1;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("effect_list")
@Expose
private List<EffectList> effectList = null;

public List<EffectList> getEffectList() {
return effectList;
}

public void setEffectList(List<EffectList> effectList) {
this.effectList = effectList;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example._1.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class _1 {

@SerializedName("effects_id")
@Expose
private String effectsId;
@SerializedName("effects_name")
@Expose
private String effectsName;

public String getEffectsId() {
return effectsId;
}

public void setEffectsId(String effectsId) {
this.effectsId = effectsId;
}

public String getEffectsName() {
return effectsName;
}

public void setEffectsName(String effectsName) {
this.effectsName = effectsName;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example._4.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class _4 {

@SerializedName("effects_id")
@Expose
private String effectsId;
@SerializedName("effects_name")
@Expose
private String effectsName;

public String getEffectsId() {
return effectsId;
}

public void setEffectsId(String effectsId) {
this.effectsId = effectsId;
}

public String getEffectsName() {
return effectsName;
}

public void setEffectsName(String effectsName) {
this.effectsName = effectsName;
}

}
```